# Polymorphism vs DownCasting

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

Let's say I have a Base class `Employee` and an derived class `Manager`, like below:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    string Name;  
};

class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
    string Designation;
};
```

While implementing some function like below:

```
Employee* SomeFunction(bool SomeCondition)
{
    Employee *Emp = NULL;
    if (SomeCondition) 
    {
       //Code goes here : Both Implementation 1 and 2 work fine!          
    }              
    return Emp;
}
```

When `SomeCondition` is true, I want to return a non-null object of type `Manager`. In such a scenario, both below pieces of code seem to fit the bill:

Implementation 1:

```
Manager *Mng = new Manager;
Mng->Name = "Adam";
Mng->Designation = "BOSS";
Emp = Mng;
```

Implementation 2:

```
Emp = new Manager;
Manager *Mng = (Manager*)Emp;
Mng->Name = "Adam";
Mng->Designation = "BOSS";
```

Since both work just fine, I would like to know which one among the two is the more efficient one?

Which one is using the concept of Polymorphism?

Is the type casting in Implementation 2 a down-cast? Is it good practice?

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? Perhaps you should retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I see some reasons behind your questions, I think you 
need to improve the your example

- you are saying that you need to return a non-null object 
  of type "Manager", while your define "SomeFunction(bool SomeCondition)" 
  to return "Employee".
- if you are indeed going to return "Employee" object why bothering 
  initializing "Designation" while you will not be able to access it 
  later. For example:

  ```
  cout << SomeFunction(true)->Designation(); // error !
  ```

So, I'm not sure what do mean by saying your examples work fine, 
since the context is not clear.

** Comparing Implementation 1 and 2 / About dynamic casting

While both examples can improve, I think Implementation 1 is slightly 
better. In both cases you do dynamic casting. However, in Implementation 
1, you do an implicit upcasting in "Emp = Mng;", while in Implementation 2 
you do downcasting in "Manager *Mng = (Manager*)Emp;".

In general you should avoid casting (especially the downcasting since it's 
not that safe all the time compared with upcasting), and if you have to 
you should use C++ style casting (e.g. dynamic_cast). See the 
example in 
https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/upcasting-downcasting.htm

A better solution is to use virtual functions in order to avoid 
casting and make room to add more objects types beside "Manager". 
For example, your header may look like:

```
class Employee
{
  public:
    virtual void setDesignation(const string & d) = 0;
    virtual string getDesignation() = 0; 
};

class Manager : public Employee
{
  public:
    virtual void setDesignation (const string & d) {Designation=d;}
    virtual string getDesignation() {return Designation;}

  private:
    string Designation;
};
```

and your function may look like:

```
Employee* SomeFunction(bool SomeCondition)
{
   Employee *Emp = NULL;
   if (SomeCondition) 
   {
     Emp = new Manager;;
     Emp->setDesignation("BOSS");             
   }              
   return Emp;
}
```

then if you want to access the Designation later, you can do

```
cout << SomeFunction(true)->getDesignation();
```

** About Polymorphism

you don't use any Polymorphism in both examples. This is becuase you don't 
use any function that is type-specific, and so your runtime behaviour doesn't 
vary depending on the "Employee" object (you are merely using one object type 
"Manager" anyways !). See the example in 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm

Answer (score 1):

Both of your implementations do what you want them to, however the second one is *very* bad practice.

First, let's clear up a misconception you seem to have: In your second implementation, you're not doing what is usually considered a downcast. You're using a C-style cast (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), which will, among casting away things such as `const`, happily cast *any* pointer to a `Manager*`. For example, you might just as well do

```
Manager *Mng = (Manager*) new Employee; // not a good idea
```

or even

```
Manager *Mng = (Manager*) new int; // now, this is really bad...
```

As a general rule, you should never use C-style casts in C++.

---

You can do a safe downcast in C++ by using `dynamic_cast`:

```
Manager *Mng = dynamic_cast<Manager*>(ptr_to_manager);  // will return a pointer to the Manager object
Manager *Mng = dynamic_cast<Manager*>(ptr_to_employee); // will return nullptr
```

Still, there is runtime overhead needed to check whether your cast is actually safe (ie, distinguish the first case in the example from the second). The need for a downcast is, by the way, usually an indication of bad design.

---

In short, the first implementation is the easier and obvious way to go: no need for an downcast, safe or unsafe.